# Network Throughput ( test on aws)

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2

We are currently conducting load balancing tests on aws.

Currently, HAProxy is running on the t2.micro instance (A) 
 Five Web services are running on the t2.micro instance. (B-1,B-2 ...)

A distributes the traffic to Group B.

As far as I know, t2.micro has an average throughput of 0.3 gbps, and if you change this to bytes, it's going to be difficult to process when it's over 37.5 mb.

However, monitoring data shows that network input bytes are 120 mb in A, and A works normally. In addition, group B has 24 mb of input bytes for each service, and the web site is normally visible.

I'm confused. Please point out the wrong part.

---------------- add ------------------

Additional test HAProxy is running on the t2.micro instance (A) 
13 Web services are running on the t2.micro instance. (B-1,B-2 ...)

[network inbyte](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNayp.png)

[network out byte](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moHoy.png)

Answer (score 0):

Main problem I see is your assumption of 0.3gpbs. Where did you find that? AWS doesn't publish network throughput in that way, they say low, medium, high. I can't find open tests online, but [this page](https://cloudonaut.io/ec2-network-performance-cheat-sheet/) says a t3.micro (not t2) can get 0.06Gbps baseline with 5Gbps burst. Basically it's going to vary, your baseline is probably a lot lower than you expected and your burst a lot higher.

Your test with 144Mbps / 18MBps sounds easily within what a t2 can do at burst. Sustained may be another matter.

In short: there is no problem here. You're saying it works when you don't think it should based on one website you found. If it works, great, if not get a larger instance size. AWS bandwidth is quite expensive, if that matters to you digital ocean or similar can be a lot cheaper.

Update: 1/10/2022 I installed SpeedTest CLI on my Ubuntu t3a.nano instance. When I ran it I got [these results](https://www.speedtest.net/result/c/5dd4446e-7981-4689-860b-9bd6c64cd810). In short, about 4.6Gbps up and down, burst.

```
   Server: eero - Hermiston, OR (id: 41819)
     ISP: Amazon.com
```

Idle Latency:     0.25 ms   (jitter: 0.02ms, low: 0.23ms, high: 0.27ms)
Download:  4691.97 Mbps (data used: 2.2 GB)
11.72 ms   (jitter: 33.55ms, low: 0.31ms, high: 222.09ms)
Upload:  4624.14 Mbps (data used: 6.7 GB)
0.57 ms   (jitter: 4.07ms, low: 0.31ms, high: 208.32ms)
Packet Loss: Not available.

Comment: 1.   https://wisen.co.kr/pages/blog/blog-detail.html?idx=7751 
I looked at this page and referenced it.

2.I think I wrote it wrong. 300Mbps -> 37500000 byte/seconds -> 37.5 MB/s  
Isn't this right?

Comment: And there is no network burst in t2. As a result of further testing, I uploaded a screenshot.
Even with such traffic, web services operate normally.

Comment: I can't remember what I was meaning with point 2 so I removed it. Yes your 37.5MBps is correct but the key problem here is you relying on that number. There's no problem here.

Comment: How come there's no problem? Does it work normally even if it exceeds the throughput?
If it works, why does it work?

Comment: There's no problem because your system is working perfectly, you're complaining that it's not broken when you expected it not to work. The only problem here is your assumption of a bandwidth limit. Use the instance. It's fine.

Comment: while researching wtf "network bandwidth out allowance exceeded" in elasticache meant, i came across this document from AWS, which includes a table of baseline bandwidth for t3 and above: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/general-purpose-instances.html#general-purpose-network-performance

according to that, t3.micro is 0.064Gbps.

i knew "up to" was bs, but i was shocked to find out just _how_ bs it was.

Comment: @CoryMawhorter I just did a speed test on my t3a.nano, have a look at the results in my updated answer.